# Use string url or URI for image properties of object

Tags: android

I want to store object to data room. when i create an object like account with name, phone number, email and images taken from gallery. Should I use string or uri for images so that objects can be easily passed between activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy images to the app's local storage and store that copied image path in the database.

For copying the image to the app's local storage after getting the selected image `uri`

```
val dir = requireActivity().getDir(FOLDER_TO_SAVE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).path
val copiedImage = File(dir, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg")
val copiedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file)

receivedImageUri.path?.let {
    File(it).copyTo(copiedImage)
}
```

Get path of the copied image, using its `uri`

```
copiedImageUri.path.?.let{
     val copiedImagePath = "file://$it"
     //now save this path to your database
}
```

Use this saved image path as `string` to exchange between `activities`.

Answer (score 0):

I think better to store this image as object `BLOB`
otherwise if you removed this image from gallery it will not be able to get this, because Room, will stored only link not an object. I hope it will be useful

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User{

@ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
private byte[] image;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but if i use byte[], can i convert from uri to bitmap, then convert bitmap to byte, pass to activity, and if i want display to imageview, i convert byte to bitmap?

Comment: @HiếuPhạm Please try this
   `byte[] bitmapdata; // let this be your byte array
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);`